# How to prevent word splitting while using eval to run a command stored in $@?

Tags: bash, ifs

I am trying to use `eval` to run a command passed into a function through `$@`.

Here is my code:

```
run_command() {
  : some logic not relevant to this question
  eval "$@"
}
```

I am running it as:

```
run_command "ls" "|" "wc -l"  # works, runs "ls | wc -l"
run_command "ls | wc -l"      # works as above
```

Now, I try to list a file that has a space in it:

```
> "file with space"
run_command "ls" "-l" "file with space"
```

This time, I get these errors:

```
ls: file: No such file or directory
ls: space: No such file or directory
ls: with: No such file or directory
```

So, it is clear that `"$@"` is resulting in word splitting.  Is there a way to prevent this issue so that `run_command` function is immune to white spaces, globs, and any other special characters?

Comment: ...if you want pipes, *and* you want an array to specify an exact argv, then you're asking for two contradictory things.

Comment: Try `eval "ls" "-l" "file with space"`, and you'll see it has the exact same problem -- demonstrating that it's not `"$@"` but `eval` that's the source of the issue.

Comment: ...note too that on a command line, `"echo" "|" "hello"` echos `| hello`, treating the pipe character as data due to its quoting -- but if we implemented what you ask for, then `run_command "echo" "|" "hello"` would treat the pipe as syntax, not data, and thus invoke a command named `hello`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Explanation

`eval` combines all arguments into a single string, and evaluates that string as code. Thus, `eval "ls" "-l" "file with space"` is exactly the same as `eval ls -l file with space` or `eval "ls -l file with space"`.

---

#### Best Practice (Without Pipe Support)

As given in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- the following runs its exact argument list as the argument vector of a simple command.

```
run_command() {
  "$@"
}
```

This offers numerous guarantees:

- No process substitution, command substitution, or other undesired operations will take place. Thus, arbitrary filenames can be passed through without double-expansion causing any part of their contents to be parsed as code.
- An argument will always be passed through to the program being run, not parsed by the shell. Thus, an array entry with the exact string `>foo` will be passed through, rather than causing a file named `foo` to be created.

If you need to wrap a command with a pipeline, this can be done by encapsulating that pipeline in a function:

```
run_pipeline() { foo "$@" | bar; }
run_command run_pipeline "argument one" "argument two"
```

---

#### Allowing Pipes As Direct Arguments

To be clear: I **do not advise using this code**. By exempting `|` from the usual protections provided by following best practices, it weakens the security provided by said practices. However, it *does* do what you ask.

```
run_command() {
  local cmd_str='' arg arg_q
  for arg; do
    if [[ $arg = "|" ]]; then
      cmd_str+=" | "
    else
      printf -v arg_q '%q' "$arg"
      cmd_str+=" $arg_q"
    fi
  done
  eval "$cmd_str"
}
```

In this form, an argument of `|` will cause the generated string to contain a *compound command*, split into simple commands at the location of that argument.

---

#### On Why This Is A Bad Idea

Now -- why is trying to allow syntax elements to be processed a Bad Idea in this context? Consider the following:

```
echo '<hello>'
```

Here, the `<` and `>` in the string `<hello>` have been quoted, and thus no longer have their original behavior. However, once you've assigned these values to an array or an argument list, as in

```
args=( 'echo' '<hello>' )
```

...metadata no longer exists about which characters were quoted or were not. Thus,

```
echo hello '|' world
```

becomes entirely indistinguishable from

```
echo hello | world
```

even though as separate commands these would have had very different behaviors.

---

#### A Concrete Example

Consider the following:

```
run_command rm -rf -- "$tempdir" "$pidfile"
```

In the "best practices" example, this is guaranteed to treat both the contents of `tempdir` and `pidfile` as filenames passed to `rm`, no matter what those values are.

However, with the "allowing pipes" example, the above could instead invoke `rm -rf -- | arbitrary-command-here`, should `tempfile='|'` and `pidfile=arbitrary-command-here`.

As shell variables are initialized from the set of environment variables present, and environment variables *are* often externally controllable -- as demonstrated by the existence of remote exploits for [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) -- this is not a purely theoretical or idle concern.